# how to convert integer from Interactive Brokers Clent Portal API to python datetime

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am using the Interactive Brokers Client Portal API to get historical data by using the package easyIB. I can't seem to find out in the documentation on how to convert the 13 digit timestamp to python's datetime.

The sample code to retrieve the data is here

```
   import easyib

   ib = easyib.REST() # default parameters: url="https://localhost:5000", ssl=False

   bars1 = ib.get_bars("AAPL", period="10w", bar="1d")
   print(bars1)
```

The output is for the part of the dataframe returned that has the open high low close volume and timestamp is here. This corresponds to one of the elements in  bars1['data']

```
[{'o': 191.46,
  'c': 190.64,
  'h': 191.52,
  'l': 189.74,
  'v': 260274.08,
  't': 1700577000000}]
```

I tried

```
   print(pd.to_datetime(1700577000000}))
```

and got something from 1970-01-01 00:28:20.577000
It should be a data point from 2023 as the request was for 10w weeks and 1 day bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is UNIX timestamp in milliseconds, if you know it is from 2023 the value should be `1700577000` since the value of `170057700000` gives the year 55859 and `pd.to_datetime` gives `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 55859-02-21 04:00:00`. If you know  the fact that data should be from 2023 , and all other timestamps are also 13 digit numbers  just divide the time stamp by 1000 as @user19077881 suggested to convert the timestamp to seconds.

Here is the alternative way to convert unix timestamp to desired string datetime format :

Input:

```
import datetime
t = 1700577000000
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t//1000).strftime('%m/%d/%Y (%H:%M:%S)')
```

Output:

```
'11/21/2023 (14:30:00)'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, (check the format of response)
[https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html#tag/Market-Data/paths/~1hmds~1history/get](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html#tag/Market-Data/paths/%7E1hmds%7E1history/get)

```
t   :
number
Time - Formatted in unix time in ms.
```

Use following to convert it

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'timestamp': [1637862000000, 1637862060000, 1637862120000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert timestamp column to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```